# Exact Search Results

Tags: search, search-results

Is there a way for e.g. searching by last name, of producing exact search results.

So if I searched for Last Name, Head.  I currently get email addresses with head in etc not just people with the surname head.

Thanks.

CIVICRM 4.5.8
Drupal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done navigating to **Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Search Preferences**, the first option is **Automatic Wildcards**, disable it.

> If enabled, wildcards are automatically added to the beginning AND end of the search term when users search for contacts by Name. EXAMPLE: Searching for 'ada' will return any contact whose name includes those letters - e.g. 'Adams, Janet', 'Nadal, Jorge', etc. If disabled, a wildcard is added to the end of the search term only. EXAMPLE: Searching for 'ada' will return any contact whose last name begins with those letters - e.g. 'Adams, Janet' but NOT 'Nadal, Jorge'. Disabling this feature will speed up search significantly for larger databases, but users must manually enter wildcards ('%' or '_') to the beginning of the search term if they want to find all records which contain those letters. EXAMPLE: '%ada' will return 'Nadal, Jorge'.

**Please note:** forgot to mention that changing this option will change the behaviour for all contact search forms, not sure if that's what you want to achieve, if it's not, @petednz comment is a very good and better answer

Comment: You could also use Search Builder (under Search in Admin menu) and set Contact Type = Individual AND Last Name = Head.

Comment: Very good addition @petednz, made me realize I assumed the question was to change search's default behavior. Answer edited.

Comment: cool - i will add my as an alternate answer then

Answer (score 2):

For undertaking a single search, which may not be what you are after, you can use Search Builder (under Search in Admin menu) and set Contact Type = Individual AND Last Name = Head